# Implementação de funções membro

Tags: c++, funções, classes, estilo-de-codificação

Estava sobrecarregando operadores e os definindo dentro da própria classe, achei natural fazer assim para essas funções, mas então surgiu uma pequena dúvida.

É errado definir funções membro dentro da própria classe? Ou é apenas uma questão de organização de código escrever os protótipos na criação da classe e depois implementá-los?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é errado se for o desejado. A definição fora existe por algumas razões, algumas mais importantes que outras, principalmente:

- A compilação separada não exige que tudo passe pelo processo de análise todas as vezes que processar a declaração classe onde estão os contratos necessários onde consome a classe e assim ganha-se tempo. Isso vale menos para as versões mais novas do C++ que possui módulos.
- É possível fazer alguma composição de implementações diferentes mantendo o mesmo contrato, o que deve ser feito com parcimônia e muito cuidado. A maioria das linguagens não permitem isso. C++ é flexível e poderosa, chega até deixar dar um tiro no pé se não manipular a arma direito.

Então é para organizar, mas por um motivo técnico e não porque fica bonitinho.

Existem casos que é (ou era) obrigado a definir a implementação junto da declaração, quando deseja certos tipos de otimização, típicos de operadores e funções muitos simples e porque aquilo faz parte de um gabarito de classe e só com o fonte junto a instância do tipo concreto precisa de todo o fonte.

Answer (score 0):

> É errado definir funções membro dentro da própria classe? Ou é apenas uma questão de organização de código escrever os protótipos na criação da classe e depois implementa-los?

Em geral é errado mesmo.

**Quando faz sentido?**

- quando você usa templates
- quando é uma classe de constantes apenas
- em programas muito simples, como programas de estudante, em que se muitas vezes se define classes e `main()` e tudo em um único arquivo fonte

Imagine o caso da classe `vector`, da classe `list`. De `iostream`. Essas classes redefinem vários operadores por exemplo. E tem muitos construtores e implementação complexa. E não se compila isso toda hora. Apenas se usa a biblioteca

Se a implementação estiver toda no header qualquer um que for usar a classe vai ler a implementação e quase nunca é o que você quer. A implementação pode não ter sido vendida, mas apenas a funcionalidade. Muita gente escreve classes como fonte de renda ;)

Se você tiver um header separado e mais o arquivo completo vai ter que manter duas vezes a mesma coisa, e isso é um risco

Se você tiver várias implementações da mesma classe em geral vai querer manter um único header com os protótipos, para sua própria segurança. E testar as implementações em vários cenários sabendo que os protótipos e estruturas são os mesmos